# YUM update on F15 borked Apache and PHP-- Why did this routine update fail?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Fedora 15 YUM update borked php and apache. This LAMP server was working fine since I upgraded to F15 last October. I'm having trouble with a PHP framework and thought an update would be useful. :doh:

```
# php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/mapi.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/mapi.so:      undefined symbol: _ZN9ECUnknown10IsParentOfEPS_ in Unknown on line 0
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
Aborted

# stemctl status httpd.service
httpd.service - LSB: start and stop Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd)
!  Active: active (exited) since Sat, 12 May 2012 13:36:58 -0400; 34min ago
   Process: 1164 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1445 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
   CGroup: name=systemd:/system/httpd.service
```

I read some completely reasonable advise suggesting [libraries](http://www.thedumbterminal.co.uk/php/knowledgebase/article/42) can get lost between updates. Unfortunately adding a soft link between /lib and /usr/lib directories where the libgcc_s.so.1 file is wanted and where it is didn't fix php and apache complains of no permissions for a socket connection.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can always roll back your last update by yum downgrade <package_name> (ie httpd) while you're investigating the issues of the broken php libraries. Just out of curiosity. What PHP version are you using ?

Comment: Do you have just standard FC15 repos installed, or are you also using things like rpmforge? Did you just update php and http, or did you yum update everything?

Comment: gyre: php 5.3.11. @becomingwisest: The yum update was just for php, httpd, and mysql. I didn't realize the pace of change was putting me into such a precarious update--I guess I should have realized 44M is a lot. I have a standard F15 install of XFCE from the Fedora main site. This is only my sandbox on a laptop, so I wanted something small and without bells and whistles of Gnome3 (>_<)